# gst-play-1.0, gst-launch-1.0 unable to display RTSP stream

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0, nvidia-jetson, jetson-xavier

I need to display an RTSP stream using the gst-play-1.0 and/ or gst-launch-1.0 commands on an NVIDIA Jetson-AGX device.

These are the commands I have tried so far:

**1. gst-play-1.0**

```
$ gst-play-1.0 rtsp://192.168.1.xxx:8554/main.264
```

in which case the terminal remains stuck at:

```
Press 'k' to see a list of keyboard shortcuts.
Now playing rtsp://192.168.1.xxx:8554/main.264
Pipeline is live.
Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 261 
NVMEDIA: Reading vendor.tegra.display-size : status: 6 
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 261 
Prerolled.
```

**2. gst-launch-1.0**

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.xxx:8554/main.264 latency=0 buffer-mode=auto ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080 ! autovideosink
```

in which case the terminal remains stuck at:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://192.168.1.xxx:8554/main.264
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
```

After pressing Ctrl+C:

```
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Execution ended after 0:00:02.188911578
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

The URLs are typically of the following formats:

```
rtsp://192.168.1.xxx:8554/main.264
rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.xxx:554
```

I am able to use the commands on a x86 PC with Ubuntu 20.04 and Gstreamer 1.16.3. So, the camera feeds themselves are fine.

But, the commands don't work on the Jetson device.

**NVIDIA Jetson-AGX device info:**

L4T 32.6.1 [ JetPack 4.6 ]

Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Kernel Version: 4.9.253-tegra

GStreamer 1.14.5

CUDA 10.2.300

CUDA Architecture: NONE

OpenCV version: 4.1.1

OpenCV Cuda: NO

CUDNN: 8.2.1.32

TensorRT: 8.0.1.6

Vision Works: 1.6.0.501

VPI: 1.1.12

Vulcan: 1.2.70

Thanks for going through the post. Any hint(s) or guidance would be most appreciated.

Thank you. :)

**Edit:**
I tried the following command, as suggested by @SeB:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.xxx:554 latency=500 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=1920,height=1080' ! nvvidconv ! autovideosink
```

and the terminal displayed the following:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.xxx:554
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 261 
NVMEDIA: Reading vendor.tegra.display-size : status: 6 
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 261 

(gst-launch-1.0:14920): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 21:59:35.771: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 261 
NVMEDIA: Reading vendor.tegra.display-size : status: 6 
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 261
```

**Edit# 2:**

Output from `gst-discoverer-1.0 rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.xxx:554` as suggested by @SeB

```
Analyzing rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.xxx:554
Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 261 
NVMEDIA: Reading vendor.tegra.display-size : status: 6 
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 261 
Done discovering rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.xxx:554

Topology:
  unknown: application/x-rtp
    video: H.264 (Main Profile)

Properties:
  Duration: 99:99:99.999999999
  Seekable: no
  Live: yes
  Tags: 
      video codec: H.264 (Main Profile)
```

Thanks for taking an interest in my query.

Comment: You may tell more about the RTSP server and what it serves or how it is launched. If both server and client are on Jetson, you would try to use localhost address 127.0.0.1.

Comment: You may also try : `gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.xxx:8554/main.264 latency=500 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=1920,height=1080' ! nvvidconv ! autovideosink`

Comment: Thanks @SeB. Will try that and get back to you, here. Also, regarding your earlier comment, the RTSP feed(s) are coming from IP cameras. I am just trying to display the feeds on Xavier. Please let me know if this addreses your point.

Comment: @Seb, i tried the command you suggested, I've updated the result in the question since it was too long for a comment. The terminal still gets stuck at a message and there is no display. Thanks.

Comment: It may depend on what is the source encoding and how much nvidia decoder may be able to handle it. You may try using ffmeg decoder instead, or try adding one queue after decoder (or more). Also try setting framerate according to your source.

Comment: What gives: `gst-discoverer-1.0 rtsp://192.168.1.xxx:8554/main.264` ? Does  `gst-play-1.0 rtsp://192.168.1.xxx:8554/main.264` works ?

Comment: Hey @SeB! I have posted the output from `gst-discoverer-1.0`. Sorry for the late reply!
Regards.

Comment: Not sure, but my guess would be that nvv4l2decoder outputs Block linear NV12 format into NVMM memory. You may try adding after decoder a queue and then either `nvvidconv bl-output=0` or if having DeepStream installed the same `bl-output=0` property with `nvvideoconvert`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted the query on NVIDIA's official forum([answer](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/gst-play-1-0-gst-launch-1-0-unable-to-display-rtsp-stream-on-xavier-agx/276025/3?u=forfuseuse)) as well as consulted some other people.

It seems that these two commands should work:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.xxx:554 latency=500 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM)' ! nv3dsink sync=0

$ gst-launch-1.0 -v uridecodebin uri=rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.xxx:554 ! nvvidconv ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink
```

Basically, it is recommended to use NVIDIA specific GStreamer plugins(prefixed by nv) on Jetson devices.